# Programming dillema - Separated objects or any other solution?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a server emulator for a certain game (It's not illegal or anything). The game has maps where players can enter and see other players in the same map and chat with them (there are also Npcs and monsters in each different maps).

I'm using C#. I created the Map class in my emulator and added basic properties (Map ID, etc). I also added a List of Characters, Npcs and Monsters. Each map has them different.

Now the dilemma I'm facing is this:

**Each channel** has it's own maps (a channel is a different 'stream', a different port where players can connect to). They're the same maps for every channel, but you can only see players on the same channel. So, say there are N maps in the game, I created N*2 maps (Consdering there are two channels) objects.

Should I go with making *different* map objects for each channel? And what if I have 20? It seems like a total waste to create objects for that. I mean, there must be another solution!

Also, my other issue is that the information the map uses (the properties) is the same for each channel, meaning it's being stored in each channel's map but it's the same for all!

Can someone maybe throw an idea to limit the use of different map objects and maybe provide me with another solution to differ between maps? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating 20 objects. A typical .NET app uses thousands upon thousands of objects. Also, those properties are pointers. So each "copy" of the map will be pointing to the same exact list objects of npcs, monsters, and players.

Comment: @KeithPayne Yes, by copies I meant differnt objects, not pointers. i'm just afraid, I don't want too much memory to be used. Isn't there another solution?

Comment: How much memory usage is too much? I ask not to be flippant but to point out that this seems like a case of [Premature Optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) (the root of all evil).